# Como expreso correctamente el idioma japones para que se refleje de manera correcta en una pagina web

Tags: html

traduje un archivo html y .txt de ingles a japones,  luego cuando intento expresarlo o reflejarlo en el servidor en donde quiero que se vea, no se ve bien el idioma. hay alguna forma especifica de como escribirlo o tengo que usar codigo ascci para cada uno de los simbolos de japones? 
ya use la etiqueta lang y no es el problema, creo que el problema es en la escritura pero no se se hay alguna forma para escribirlo y que se refleje bien en pantalla, gracias.

Comment: Responde esta busqueda de [google](http://www.nobadmemories.com/blog/2017/04/better-together-displaying-japanese-and-english-text-on-the-web/) tu problema ?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.